# Detecting if input view is less date than today

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, nsdate

I'm trying to determine if the user set a date picker to a day less than today. E.g, today is `4/23/17`, so I want to detect if the user does like 4/15/17 or like 2/4/17. Basically anything less than the date. I'm kind of stuck. If you know how to do it, please help.

Comment: `NSCalendar` provides a lot of methods to do date math.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `NSDate`? What trouble exactly are you having? [Edit] your question with relevant code.

Comment: You can use:  if( [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate] > 0 ) { //Do your stuff}

Comment: @IPSBrar Why not simply compare the two date objects with the `compare:` method?

Comment: @rmaddy there are a lot of methods to do so, I used what I think is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];

if([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending)
{

}
```

Comment: Code only answers are low quality and candidates for deletion, there should always be at least 1 or 2 sentences explaining what part of the question you are answering.